# How to set a custom format for the Amount in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to set custom amount format for Negative value in excel.

i have a amount in format 1,11,111 with negative sign.

Ex:- **-1,12,000**

Comment: Can you please add more background to this question? What is the value being displayed currently? What is the expected value (format)?

Comment: As @KarthickGanesan mentioned, it's not clear what your value represents. It can't be an integer with separators in those positions. Perhaps a typo?

Comment: @Owen I think the Poster wants an Indian Rupee Format, but with a negative sign for negative values

Comment: Aha. TIL "lakh". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve negative amounts with crore and lakh using this custom format:

```
[<-9999999]-#\,##\,##\,##0.00;[<-99999]-#\,##\,##0.00;##,##0.0
```

But to have this apply to all of your workbooks (and your computer), you can go to Control Panel, Clock & Region, Change date, time or number formats, Additional settings then change the digit grouping drop-down.

[image]